# How do I make .htaccess such that going to the folder will show the contents of the folder?

Tags: web-services, .htaccess

How do I make .htaccess such that going to the folder in the web browser, where .htacess resides, will show the contents of the folder?  Maye this is not something achieved by .htacess file but has something to do with changing the permission of the folder("directory").

I do not want to use an index.html file at all because the contents of the directory (folder) will change and then the index.html will be invalid.

I have a follow-up question.  After this is done, is there then a way to programmatically use C# code to get the contents of the directory listing?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by contents of the folder? You mean directory listing?

Comment: Yes, a directory listing.

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to access your folders directory via the web browser:

All you need to add is:

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
 IndexOptions FancyIndexing IconHeight=16 IconWidth=16
</ifModule>
```

You will get something that looks a bit like this:

[image]

You can of course play around with the settings and add extra things like:

```
NameWidth=25
DescriptionWidth=40
IconsAreLinks
```

This is not necessary though, it really depends if this is just for you, or public access too. Does it need to be pretty :P

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `.htaccess` file inside that `specific` folder then add this at the top of the .htaccess file. Remove any index.html file that you have there also.

```
Options +Indexes
```